# Let $H\le G$ with $|G:H|=n<\infty$. Let $\varpi$ be the set of all primes not exceeding $n$. Then $G/H_G$ is a finite $\varpi$-group

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

This is **Exercise 191** of Rose's *"A Course in Group Theory"*.

### The Details:

From p. 38 *ibid*.,

> **Definition:** Let $H\le G$ and define $$H_G=\bigcap_{g\in G}(g^{-1}Hg).$$ [. . .] It is called the *core* (or *normal interior*) of $H$ in $G$.

From p. 56 *ibid*.,

> **Definition:** [Here] $\varpi$ is a set of prime numbers. [. . .] A positive integer $n$ is said to be a *$\varpi$-number* if every prime divisor of $n$ belongs to $\varpi$. [. . .] We say $G$ is a *$\varpi$-group* if $\lvert G\rvert$ is a $\varpi$-number.

### The Question:

> Let $H\le G$ with $|G:H|=n<\infty$. Let $\varpi$ be the set of all primes not exceeding $n$. Then $G/H_G$ is a finite $\varpi$-group.

This is on page 75.

### Context:

My progress in Rose's book and my memory of the preceding material have both been stunted by this question. I have made little if any progress on it.

---

I think the group ${\rm Inn}(G)$ of inner automorphisms of $G$ might play an important role here.

---

*An Example:*

Let $\varpi=\{ 2,3\}$, $\Bbb Z_2\cong H\le G\cong \Bbb Z_6$. Then $n=[G:H]=3<\infty$. Suppose $G$ is generated by $a$. Then $H=\langle a^3\rangle$. We have

$$\begin{align}
H_G&=\bigcap_{g\in G}(g^{-1}Hg)\\
&=H\cap\{ a^{-1}ha:h\in H\}\\
&\cap\{ a^{-2}ha^2:h\in H\}\\
&\cap\{ a^{-3}ha^3:h\in H\}\\
&\cap\{ a^{-4}ha^4:h\in H\}\\
&\cap\{ a^{-5}ha^5:h\in H\}\\
&=\bigcap_{i=1}^6\langle a^3\rangle\\
&=H.
\end{align}$$

Then $G/H_G\cong G/H\cong \Bbb Z_3,$ which is indeed a finite $\varpi$-group.

Perhaps the choice of $G$ and $H$ is not helpful as they are both finite and cyclic (and hence abelian).

Something more instructive might be found in $G=S_3$, say, as that is the smallest nonabelian group, or in $2\Bbb Z\le \Bbb Z$, since they're infinite (although then $\varpi=\{2\}$, which doesn't tell us much).

---

I suspect that, with more time, I'd be able to answer this myself, but I've already spent "too long" on it for a recreational/peripheral exercise. I get the feeling that I'm missing some important conceptual aspect of the problem though.

The type of answer I'm hoping for is a strong hint or a full proof (to address what it is I don't understand yet).

---

Please help :)

Comment: There's an action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$.

Comment: Consider the permutation action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. The order of the image divides $n!$ and the kernel is $H_G$.

Comment: The point of the above is that there's a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to S_n$ with kernel $H_G$ and any subgroup of $S_n$ is a $\varpi$-group.

Comment: @Shaun Are you able to complete the exercise with the hints above? If so, how about writing up the answer?